Sticky bar Issues I can't trace. I need guidance
My sticky tabs wont stick. I have edited my CSS, adjusted it and checked all my code line after line but i dont seem to see the issue. All browsers wont show it but I am not sure what is prohibiting it from showing.
See the code below
<div id="layout" class="clearfix l-two-column-left">
       Header content is here
        <div class="content-container l-container clearfix">
            <div class="content-column">
                <div style="padding-bottom: 50px;">
                    <div class="sticky-tabs">
                        <ul class="tabs-nav">
                            <li><a href="#why-it-matters">Why It Matters</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Resources">Resources</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#What-we-do">Our Approach</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Policy-center">Our Policies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Take-action">Get Involved</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="main" tabindex="-1" role="main" class="main">
                    <!-- Content Sections -->
                    <div class="m content-sections">
                        <section id="why-it-matters">
                            <h3 class="subheader"><span class="design"></span> Subtitle</h3>
                            <h2>Header</h2>
                            <p class="work">content</p>
                        </section>
                        <div class="m content-sections">
                            <section id="Resources">
                                <h3 class="subheader"><span class="design"></span>Resources</h3>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="m content-sections">
                            <section id="What-we-do">
                                <h3 class="subheader"><span class="design"></span>subtitle</h3>
                                <h2>title</h2>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <section id="Policy-center" class="m">
                            <h3 class="subheader"><span class="design"></span>Subtitle</h3>
                            <h2>title</h2>
                        </section>
                         Side bar starts here and ends here too
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


And below is part of my CSS Code that addresses the stick
 .sticky-tabs {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* For Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; /* Adjust this value to your needs */
  z-index: 1000; /* Ensure it appears above other elements */
  padding: 10px 0; /* Optional: Adjust padding */
}



I have tried to troubleshoot by disabling my scripts but, that didnt work. Cant trace theproblem. If there is code i can use to bypass this problem from wherever it comes from that is not a plugin, that'd be very helpful I Have also tried to use the code in another browser but it doesnt work, however a page withour CSS from the main file sticks.
Code is beyond the limited xters here.

I see two problems at first glance.

You have a conflict with other parts of the code.
Keep in mind that the essence of sticky elements is also that they must have a place to stick... In other words, the container with content should be of the right height or have the right amount of content.

Try manipulating the height of the container...
Take a look


.sticky-tabs {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.content-column {
  padding: 20px;
}

.main {
  padding: 20px;
}

section {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
 <div id="layout" class="clearfix l-two-column-left">
<div class="header">
    Header content is here
</div>
<div class="content-container l-container clearfix">
    <div class="content-column">
        <div class="sticky-tabs">
            <ul class="tabs-nav">
                <li><a href="#why-it-matters">Why It Matters</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Resources">Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#What-we-do">Our Approach</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Policy-center">Our Policies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Take-action">Get Involved</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main" tabindex="-1" role="main" class="main">
            <section id="why-it-matters">
                <h2>Why It Matters</h2>
                <p>Content here</p>
            </section>
            <section id="Resources">
                <h2>Resources</h2>
                <p>Content here</p>
            </section>
            <section id="What-we-do">
                <h2>Our Approach</h2>
                <p>Content here</p>
            </section>
            <section id="Policy-center">
                <h2>Our Policies</h2>
                <p>Content here</p>
            </section>
            <section id="Take-action">
                <h2>Get Involved</h2>
                <p>Content here</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>




Thank you for this but it still doesnt work.

@SenkyaAndy Could you show your full CSS and HTML?

I have edited the code but the CSS requires more xters.

@SenkyaAndy Check updated code, please. If now will not be working then for sure is something wrong in rest of your css.

I have looked through my CSS and i cant tell whats stopping the sticky section to stick. It is still failing even after the second attemp
